# Automatic Bitmap stretch to fit ImageView

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview, scale

I have a Bitmap that is 80dp * 80dp. The ImageView size is automatically scaled.
The ImageView size is: 130DP * 130DP (Bigger than the bitmap size).

I was trying to fit the bitmap into the imageView size (I don't mind about losing image quality).

Here's some code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <com.inturnex.safecam.SquareImageView 
       android:id="@+id/imageView" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/locked_image"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

I am setting the bitmap programatically. The ImageView takes 130DP in size, but the image I see is in the size of 80DP (as the original bitmap and it doesn't stretch to fit the ImageView size).

What can I do in order to achieve that task? Thank you!

**EDIT:** SquareImageView implementation:

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {
    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); //Snap to width
    }
}
```

Comment: @Stacks28 See the code, there is use of the FitXY. Oh I didn't try programatically.

Comment: use programtically imageview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

Comment: @Stacks28 Still, same result.

Comment: What kind of an object is com.inturnex.safecam.SquareImageView? I'd try with a plain old imageView before I'd turn to a custom object...

Comment: @Stacks28 Could you provide an example of image thumnail? How can it help me? I am looking for the best memory solution.

Comment: now only problem is ur bitmap stretching right

Comment: @DigCamara I tried using the regular ImageView.With your idea, the height really is 130DP but the width is 80DP (Instead of 130DP * 130DP). I edited my post with the SquareImageView implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use the scaling to Matrix (either programatically or in xml)

```
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
imageView.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

Here, Dalvik takes your image, applies the scaling Matrix so it fills your ImageView.  Your drawableRect should contain the dimensions of your Bitmap, your viewRect, the dimensions of your `imageView`.